# SQL not working within a python function when printed reflects as a string

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sapui5

I am trying to run SQL code to retrieve data from IBM DB2 within a python function that is retrieving data from SAP GUI and based on certain criteria pull the data from IBM DB2. When i print the connection of DB2 it works. However the SQL code is being printed as a string. Note that i have not mentioned the entire code to login in to SAP  as it would be very long. When run the same script separately it works fine retrieving the required data. Any idea why it is considering it like a string not a SQL script.

result of the query:

```
<ibm_db_dbi.Connection object at 0x000002B8DF807588>
Select * from DBA.M82 T82 
WHERE T82.EID IN 324809
```

Code is:

```
import win32com.client
import sys
import subprocess
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from multiprocessing import Process
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import ibm_db
import ibm_db_dbi as db

def sap_login()

dsn = "DRIVER={{IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER}};" + \
      "DATABASE=;" + \
      "HOSTNAME=;" + \
      "PORT=;" + \
      "UID=;" + \
      "PWD=;"

hdbc  = db.connect(dsn, "", "")
e_id=session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlBCALV_GRID_DEMO_0100_CONT1/shellcont/shell").GetCellValue(i,"ZEMP_CODE")
sql=(""" Select * 
         from DBA.M82 T82 
         WHERE T82.EID in {}""").format(e_id)

print(sql)
                                fsdd=pd.read_sql(sql,hdbc)

sap_login()
```

Comment: You basically assign the string to a variable and then print it. You need to use a function within the ibm_db package and use the sql variable as an argument.

Comment: Martin i am using IBM db package import ibm_db
import ibm_db_dbi as db

Comment: Resolved the issue by removing the bracket. What i learnt from this within a function while i am using a bracket it is being considered as a string

Answer (score 0):

```
import win32com.client
import sys
import subprocess
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from multiprocessing import Process
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import ibm_db
import ibm_db_dbi as db

def sap_login()

dsn = "DRIVER={{IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER}};" + \
      "DATABASE=;" + \
      "HOSTNAME=;" + \
      "PORT=;" + \
      "UID=;" + \
      "PWD=;"

hdbc  = db.connect(dsn, "", "")
e_id=session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlBCALV_GRID_DEMO_0100_CONT1/shellcont/shell").GetCellValue(i,"ZEMP_CODE")
sql=""" Select * 
         from DBA.M82 T82 
         WHERE T82.EID in {}""".format(e_id)

print(sql)
                                fsdd=pd.read_sql(sql,hdbc)
```

A note you would need to convert your list to tuples while using format to pull data for multiple values.